# A remarkable produc with twice the product of the three terms: $2abc$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It is well-known that
$$(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab, \ \ \ a,b\in\mathbb R$$
Let us consider twice the product of the two terms: $2ab$.

I have a curiosity. Is there a remarkable product that has twice the product of the three terms: $2abc$?

For example, for $(a+b+c)^2$, $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$, this does not happen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by remarkable, but a silly one is $(a+bc)^2$. Also, $(a+b+c)^3$ has $6abc$.

Comment: In the expansion of $(a+b+c)^2$  all terms are of degree two. So you can not expect a degree three term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is one.

$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=a^2(b+c)+b^2(c+a)+c^2(a+b)+2abc$